# Pytest is only passing the first test of my cli in the module, and failing the next, reguardless of ordering. Why is this happening?

Tags: python, unit-testing, click, pytest, typer

pytest version: pytest==7.1.2

typer version: typer==0.4.1

I have this test file

```
import pytest
from mimicbot import (
    __app_name__,
    cli,
    config,
)
import typer
from typer.testing import CliRunner, Result
from configparser import ConfigParser
from pathlib import Path 

default_path = Path(config.APP_DIR_PATH)
default_config = default_path / "config.ini"

@pytest.fixture
def mock_config_path(tmp_path):
    tmp_config_path = tmp_path / "config.ini"
    config.init_app(tmp_path)
    # copy a file from path default_config and paste it to tmp_config_path
    tmp_config_path.write_text(default_config.read_text())
    return tmp_config_path


class TestMine:
    # Must have an initialized mimicbot config to the default parameters
    def test_successful_mine(self, mock_config_path, tmp_path):
        parsed_config = ConfigParser()
        parsed_config.read(str(mock_config_path))
        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(cli.app, ["mine", "-ap", tmp_path])

        data_path = tmp_path / "data" / parsed_config.get("discord", "guild") / parsed_config.get("general", "session")
        messages_path = data_path / "messages.csv"

        assert "Successfully mined data." in result.stdout
        assert result.exit_code == 0
        assert messages_path.exists()
    
    def test_failed_mine_api_key(self, mock_config_path, tmp_path):
        parsed_config = ConfigParser()
        parsed_config.read(str(mock_config_path))
        parsed_config.set("discord", "api_key", "xxFAKExx")
        with open(str(mock_config_path), "w") as config_file:
            parsed_config.write(config_file)

        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(cli.app, ["mine", "-ap", tmp_path])

        assert "Error: API_KEY_ERROR" in result.stdout
        assert result.exit_code == 1
```

I am running those two tests which depend on waiting for the cli to execute. The cli depends on a function which takes a couple seconds to run.

Reguardless of how I order the two tests I always get the same result: the first one (sequentially) passes while the following one fails.

When running the former file I get the following traceback.

> ======================================== test session starts ======================================== platform win32 -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0 rootdir: C:\Projects\MimicBot\mimicbotwrapper, configfile: pytest.ini plugins:
> asyncio-0.18.3 asyncio: mode=auto collected 8 items
>
> tests\test_init.py ......
> [ 75%] tests\test_mine.py .F
> [100%]
>
> ============================================= FAILURES ==============================================
> _________________________________ TestMine.test_failed_mine_api_key _________________________________
>
> self = <tests.test_mine.TestMine object at 0x00000230BB8C3BB0>
> mock_config_path =
> WindowsPath('C:/Users/1seba/AppData/Local/Temp/pytest-of-1seba/pytest-67/test_failed_mine_api_key0/config.ini')
> tmp_path =
> WindowsPath('C:/Users/1seba/AppData/Local/Temp/pytest-of-1seba/pytest-67/test_failed_mine_api_key0')
>
> ```
> def test_failed_mine_api_key(self, mock_config_path, tmp_path):
>     parsed_config = ConfigParser()
>     parsed_config.read(str(mock_config_path))
>     parsed_config.set("discord", "api_key", "xxFAKExx")
>     with open(str(mock_config_path), "w") as config_file:
>         parsed_config.write(config_file)
>
>     runner = CliRunner()
>     result = runner.invoke(cli.app, ["mine", "-ap", tmp_path])
> ```
>
> > ```
> >   assert "Error: API_KEY_ERROR" in result.stdout E       AssertionError: assert 'Error: API_KEY_ERROR' in '' E        +  where
> > ```
>
> '' = <Result RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')>.stdout
>
> tests\test_mine.py:51: AssertionError
> ========================================= warnings summary ==========================================  tests/test_mine.py::TestMine::test_successful_mine
> tests/test_mine.py::TestMine::test_failed_mine_api_key
> C:\Projects\MimicBot\mimicbotwrapper\env\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:229:
> DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
> self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() if loop is None else loop
>
> tests/test_mine.py::TestMine::test_failed_mine_api_key
> C:\Projects\MimicBot\mimicbotwrapper\env\lib\site-packages_pytest\unraisableexception.py:78:
> PytestUnraisableExceptionWarning: Exception ignored in: <function
> _ProactorBasePipeTransport.**del** at 0x00000230AE62E830>
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in **del**
> self.close()
> File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
> self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
> File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
> self._check_closed()
> File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
> raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')   RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
>
> ```
> warnings.warn(pytest.PytestUnraisableExceptionWarning(msg))
> ```
>
> -- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
> ====================================== short test summary info ======================================  FAILED tests/test_mine.py::TestMine::test_failed_mine_api_key -
> AssertionError: assert 'Error: API_...============================== 1
> failed, 7 passed, 3 warnings in 5.24s ==============================
> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run..runner' was
> never awaited

Then when the ordering (beginning of file to end) of the tests is flipped, I get the following traceback:

> ======================================== test session starts ======================================== platform win32 -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0 rootdir: C:\Projects\MimicBot\mimicbotwrapper, configfile: pytest.ini plugins:
> asyncio-0.18.3 asyncio: mode=auto collected 8 items
>
> tests\test_init.py ......
> [ 75%] tests\test_mine.py .F
> [100%]
>
> ============================================= FAILURES ==============================================
> ___________________________________ TestMine.test_successful_mine ___________________________________
>
> self = <tests.test_mine.TestMine object at 0x000001AB03A9E410>
> mock_config_path =
> WindowsPath('C:/Users/1seba/AppData/Local/Temp/pytest-of-1seba/pytest-68/test_successful_mine0/config.ini')
> tmp_path =
> WindowsPath('C:/Users/1seba/AppData/Local/Temp/pytest-of-1seba/pytest-68/test_successful_mine0')
>
> ```
> def test_successful_mine(self, mock_config_path, tmp_path):
>     parsed_config = ConfigParser()
>     parsed_config.read(str(mock_config_path))
>     runner = CliRunner()
>     result = runner.invoke(cli.app, ["mine", "-ap", tmp_path])
>
>     data_path = tmp_path / "data" / parsed_config.get("discord", "guild") / parsed_config.get("general", "session")
>     messages_path = data_path / "messages.csv"
> ```
>
> > ```
> >   assert "Successfully mined data." in result.stdout E       AssertionError: assert 'Successfully mined data.' in '' E        +
> > ```
>
> where '' = <Result RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')>.stdout
>
> tests\test_mine.py:48: AssertionError
> ========================================= warnings summary ==========================================  tests/test_mine.py::TestMine::test_failed_mine_api_key
> tests/test_mine.py::TestMine::test_successful_mine
> C:\Projects\MimicBot\mimicbotwrapper\env\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:229:
> DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
> self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() if loop is None else loop
>
> tests/test_mine.py::TestMine::test_successful_mine
> C:\Projects\MimicBot\mimicbotwrapper\env\lib\site-packages_pytest\unraisableexception.py:78:
> PytestUnraisableExceptionWarning: Exception ignored in: <function
> _ProactorBasePipeTransport.**del** at 0x000001AB7681E830>
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in **del**
> self.close()
> File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
> self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
> File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
> self._check_closed()
> File "C:\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
> raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')   RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
>
> ```
> warnings.warn(pytest.PytestUnraisableExceptionWarning(msg))
> ```
>
> -- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
> ====================================== short test summary info ======================================  FAILED tests/test_mine.py::TestMine::test_successful_mine - AssertionError:
> assert 'Successfully mi...============================== 1 failed, 7
> passed, 3 warnings in 2.23s ==============================  sys:1:
> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run..runner' was never
> awaited

In the end it seems like the same issue is happening on both files as they fail in the same manner.

I have also tried moving the tests to separate files (crap solution in my opinion) and that also failed in the same way.

What could be the problem?
How could I resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stack overflow. Check out the formatting guide in the [help center](/help/formatting) - can you use code blocks, e.g. with triple back ticks instead of quote blocks? That will make these tracebacks much easier to read. Thanks!

Comment: looks like there is issues with `asyncio`, probably due to the fact that the `discord` library uses `async` code

Comment: I think so too, although i am not sure how to overcome it as I have used pytest-asyncio and ran the tests asynchronously but that breaks the tests as I cannot await the CliRunner.